# Transfer of Ethereum coinbase wallet to ethereum wallet

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, coinbase

I have been perusing these wonderful threads for about a week now to get a better understanding of Ether and the ecosystem. I recently downloaded the Ethereum wallet client from the Ethereum website to secure my Ether that I purchased via Coinbase. I sent a small amount of Ether from my Coinbase to my Ethereum wallet and noticed that the amount sent was too small and that the gas price was higher than the amount sent. I canceled the transaction since the price to transfer exceeded the transfer amount.

Coinbase now shows that the request was executed successfully, but the amount sent is neither in my Coinbase wallet nor in my Ethereum wallet via the Ethereum client.

Anyone have any ideas as to where that portion of Ether is?

Answer (score 2):

If Coinbase said they sent a transaction, they probably did that. Probably your local wallet isn't completely syncronized and that is why you don't see your balance. Use an online explorer (i.e. [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/)) to check your real balance.

Comment: Thanks Guiseppe. The real balance does show the amount I sent. Now how should I go about synchronizing my local ethereum wallet to match what etherscan.io shows. In addition to this, what suggestions do you have for keeping one's ether secured?